# Second largest value is showing wrong value on pandas dataframe, when groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table, and I'm trying to get the second largest "percent" value by column "Day".
I can get the second largest value, but the column 'Hour', is not the right one

Table:df

| name | Day | Hour | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 10 | 0.908494 |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 11 | 0.831482 |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 12 | 0.843846 |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 13 | 0.877238 |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 17 | 0.163908 |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 18 | 0.230296 |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 19 | 0.359440 |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 20 | 0.379988 |

Script Used:
df = df.groupby(['name','Day'])[['Hour','percent']].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, columns='percent').min())

Output:
As you can see, the "Hour" value is wrong. It should be "13" and not "10". The second largest value is right.

| name | Day | Hour | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 10 | 0.877238 |

It should be:

| name | Day | Hour | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000_RJ_S1 | 26 | 13 | 0.877238 |

I can't figure out what's is wrong. Could you guys help me with this issue.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Based on the precision shown, the two rows are tied.  Keep in mind that floating point is not exact.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the `percent` columns before grouping, and use the `nth` function instead:

```py
(df.sort_values('percent', ascending=False)
  .groupby(['name', 'Day'],sort=False, as_index = False)
  .nth(1)
) 
        name  Day  Hour   percent
3  000_RJ_S1   26    13  0.877238
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I didn't know about this "nth" function. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have got 10 is because of the `min()` function.

The `nlargest()` in the lambda would return the two rows with largest percent values and when you apply `min()` what it does is it selects the minimum values from each column separately which gave you that output.

You can use `iloc[1]` instead of `min()` to get the desired result

Here's the code using iloc:

```
df.groupby(['name','Day'])[['Hour','percent']].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, columns='percent')).iloc[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for clarify about de "min()" function. Thats was my issue, it was getting the min for each column.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a double `groupby`:

```
cols = ['name','Day']
# get the top 2 per group
s = df.groupby(cols)['percent'].nlargest(2)
# get the index of min per group
idx = s.droplevel(cols).groupby(s.droplevel(-1).index).idxmin()
# slice original data with those indexes
df2 = df.loc[idx.values]
```

Output:

```
        name  Day  Hour   percent
3  000_RJ_S1   26    13  0.877238
```